# How can I change the labels on a chart created with the Google Chart Tools module?

Tags: 7, charts, google-search-console

I'm using both the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module and the [Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) module to create a chart from  the data that I'm collecting from registered users.

Here is a sample of my chart:

[image]

But how can I change the labels of the X-axis?

And I want the title to appear on the X-axis also, instead of the link. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is very easy. Simply uncheck **link field to original piece of content** of the field you are using.

[image]

Comment: I dont have that option. Mine just shows "create a label" and "exclude from display"

Comment: I've created a new content type, called personal where user can enter test information. and the field i want show it in the graph is an integer (the test score)

Comment: I meant the field showing the url on the horizontal axis

Comment: umm it is content,sorry i'm quite a noob with drupal>_<

Comment: Content:title ??

Comment: no, it has the test score field name ,, content:(the test score field)

Comment: Can you put a print screen of what the field configuration looks like in your question

Comment: the word in the formatter list, is default, and the one above "test score" is field name